# Horrible ImageView bitmap quality?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I've got a splash screen with an `ImageView` playing the part of a background. Regardless of whether or not I allow my bitmap to be scaled (which I do), the image quality is horrible. I think it's reducing the color depth. I've looked around SO already and one suggestion was to place my image in `raw` instead of `drawable` but that didn't help either. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

What exactly is going on here and how do I fix it?

EDIT: I didn't apply this bitmap programmatically so there's no relevant Java code. Here is the XML code for this activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayoutSplash"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:drawingCacheQuality="high"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/splash_padding"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    tools:context=".SplashActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageViewBg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo_description"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_bg_register" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageViewLogo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo_description"
        android:maxHeight="@dimen/logo_maxheight"
        android:maxWidth="@dimen/logo_maxwidth"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewCopyright"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/copyright"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/white_50"
        android:textSize="@dimen/copyright_size" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT: I tried `getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);` as suggested which made a visible difference but the banding is still present. [This](http://goo.gl/oSHrp) is the image I'm using as the background.

Comment: post your code.

Comment: what is the size of the image?

Comment: Set android:scaleType to **matrix**

Comment: No, that doesn't scale the image properly. @Arju, it is 1000px high by 800px wide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Banding occurs mostly when aspect ratio of the image is disturbed.

You could try any one of the following:

1. Make your image `.9.png`. In that case, it will automatically fix any stretches and take care of banding.
2. Apply superficial dithering to your image which might prevent any unusual banding.

   ```
   <bitmap
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:src="@drawable/b1"
       android:tileMode="repeat"
       android:dither="true" />
   ```

Answer (score 2):

What are the dimentions of your image? And what is the device?
What I suspect is that image size does not match the size of the display and it is in wrong resource drawable folder. The image looks pretty scaled. These articles should help you out picking the image resolution and resource folder for different screens.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

Comment: I updated the question to link to a copy of the image I'm using as the background. It is 1000x800px. I'm testing on a Galaxy S Blaze device. I'm using a `<bitmap>` XML resource referencing `splash_bg.png`. It is scaled to fit the height of the target device's screen. Width is cropped.

Comment: No need to create a bitmap xml. Just set the image and scaleType centerCrop is correct. For Galaxy Blaze try making a copy of your image with resolution 480x800 and put it in drawable-normal-hdpi folder.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set window color format. In your activity put something like this:

```
getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
```

Comment: This worked to an extent. I can see some visible difference, but I'm still seeing the same banding artifacts. Any idea of what to try next?

Answer (score 1):

I guess size of image is smaller than the area in which image is displayed. So, may be image is scaling up and loosing the quality.

```
What you can try is:

1. Either put the image of similar dimension 
2. use 9 patch image ( good idea )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to resize your image into different sizes and put those into respective drawable folders under `res/`

Answer (score 0):

Try antialias this may solved you problem.

Create a bitmap drawable with the below xml.

```
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:antialias="true"
    android:dither="true"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

> What you are doing is to set the image in xml that much more depends
>   on what that image resolution  support  for .

there is a number of folders for each supported density  of multiple  devices ,  put your image on some suitable folder of dpi .

please refer this link for it http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

see same  app icon how behave diffidently in different folder

Example application without support for different densities, as shown on low, medium, and high density screens

[image: Example application without support for different densities, as shown on low, medium, and high density screens.]

[image]

Example application with good support for different densities (it's density independent), as shown on low, medium, and high density screens.

Answer (score 0):

Just tweak it by making the image a background image. Here is a sample code

```
   <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/your_image"
    />
```